# Which kind of data breaches or risk can happen if there is no virtual/physical disk encryption

Tags: encryption, appsec, data-leakage, azure

There is an Azure-based internal database server and is not public-facing.  There is another front-end application. A specific user group can connect with a VPN. There is no encryption applied at the disk level. So what risk or specific gap can impact the business at a larger level?

What kind and types of risk pertain OR the possibility of a breach in the lack of encryption? Also what kind of controls can be used to prevent this?

Comment: First things first: what types of threats is this control meant to counter? Disk encryption prevents threats at the physical level.

Comment: Threat can be discussed.

Comment: But if the control only matters for physical access to media, then the threat is pre-defined, and your risk assessment is clear: physical access to media. Is this a school question?

Comment: The question is about if there is a Azure virtual disk and it is the internal server ( Not public facing). There is another front end application. The specific user group has connected with the specific VPN and SHA 256 for the hash. 

There is no encrpytion at the disk level.  So what risk or specfic gap can impact the business at larger level?  How can we prevent of it?

Comment: Like I said, it is only a risk if there is physical access to the storage media. Disk encryption doesn't apply as a control if you can read the database.

Comment: Is this a school question?

Answer (score 0):

Encryption at rest generally only protects three scenarios:

1. Attacker with physical access to the machine, who can pull the storage device and connect it to their own machine. In theory the attacker could instead have file-level or even block-level access but lack the decryption key, but in practice that's unlikely as the operating system would not permit such access to an unauthorized user and an authorized one could just grab the key.
2. Offline backups in the form of clones of the data storage, where the backup might be compromised (this happens a lot, such as somebody breaking into a car and stealing backup tapes or similar). This doesn't apply if the backup is created by the software reading and transcribing from its online data storage (you still need to encrypt the backup in that case, but it doesn't matter whether the primary is encrypted or not because the application obviously has the key).
3. Disposal of old storage, especially worn-out or malfunctioning storage that is hard to wipe securely (if the data is only ever written encrypted and the key is never present with it, then there's no plain text to steal). Used storage frequently winds up on the second-hand market (by itself or as part of a complete machine), sometimes incorrectly erased or not erased at all. "Dead" drives' data also often can be recovered using more sophisticated equipment, but might be thrown away as no longer sensitive because "they can't be read". Encryption makes it easy to decommission storage devices, whether they're operational or not; just delete the key (which should be on a separate device). This is more foolproof and less expensive than e.g. physically shredding storage.

For a cloud provider, #1 applies if you don't trust the data center employees (though hopefully they're trustworthy or at least there's enough data center security that nobody can act unilaterally and there's not multiple conspirators); #2 applies if the backups are generated from the raw storage and you don't necessarily know if they are (and also usually can't directly control the security of the backups, though hopefully it's good); #3 applies when the data center retires hardware which is not under your control (though hopefully they publish their hardware decommissioning process and hopefully it's both sufficient and reliably followed).